# Can we set unique id for any field with pdf to html converter?

Tags: pdftk, pdf-to-html

[Click here to view image of editable pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nX28K.png)

I need to convert editable pdf to html and want to display all editable fields with unique_id.Is it possible with a converter ?
Below is the html of pdf after conversion. Here tags as well as attributes for checkboxes elements are almost same, I need to differentiate these elements independently. Is there any way i can read them separately.

```
 <p style="position:absolute;top:979px;left:110px;white-space:nowrap"    class="ft11">Deutsch</p>
 <p style="position:absolute;top:979px;left:255px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft11">English</p>
 <p style="position:absolute;top:979px;left:401px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft11">Français</p>
 <p style="position:absolute;top:979px;left:537px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft11">Esperanto</p>
 <p style="position:absolute;top:979px;left:683px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft11">Latin</p>
 <p style="position:absolute;top:567px;left:252px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft11"><img src="../../../images/lookup.gif"  id="Imgt0" onclick="div_show('t0')"></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:616px;left:252px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft11"><img src="../../../images/lookup.gif"  id="Imgt1" onclick="div_show('t1')"></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:665px;left:252px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft11"><img src="../../../images/lookup.gif"  id="Imgt7" onclick="div_show('t7')"></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:665px;left:571px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft11"><img src="../../../images/lookup.gif"  id="Imgt2" onclick="div_show('t2')"></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:695px;left:252px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft11"><img src="../../../images/lookup.gif"  id="Imgt3" onclick="div_show('t3')"></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:725px;left:252px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft11"><img src="../../../images/lookup.gif"  id="Imgt4" onclick="div_show('t4')"></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:725px;left:449px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft11"><img src="../../../images/lookup.gif"  id="Imgt6" onclick="div_show('t6')"></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:774px;left:252px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft11"><img src="../../../images/lookup.gif"  id="ImgYes" onclick="div_show('Yes')"></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:823px;left:252px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft11"><img src="../../../images/lookup.gif"  id="ImgYes" onclick="div_show('Yes')"></p>
 <p style="position:absolute;top:871px;left:252px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft11"><img src="../../../images/lookup.gif"  id="Imgt5" onclick="div_show('t5')"></p>
 <p style="position:absolute;top:915px;left:249px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft11">✘</p>
  <p style="position:absolute;top:981px;left:89px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft11">✘</p>
  <p style="position:absolute;top:981px;left:235px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft11">✘</p>
  <p style="position:absolute;top:981px;left:380px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft11">✘</p>
  <p style="position:absolute;top:981px;left:517px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft11">✘</p>
 <p style="position:absolute;top:981px;left:662px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft11">✘</p>
```

Comment: Do you have any solution then tell ? how to do it with pdf to html converter.

Comment: Thanks Bruno.Actually i am having a editable non-tagged pdf with some checkboxes. When i convert pdf to html, I am unable to differentiate these checkboxes as they all having the same class.Is there any way so that i can read them independently ?

Comment: I have edited the question. Please have a look and suggest me anything if you can.